# Ant task failed in jenkins because spanish characters on comments

Tags: java, ant, jenkins

In my project there are several classes with spanish character in comments or strings. In order to build it I use an apache ant task. When executed from command line, the ant task works fine and compiles everything. When runned from Jenkings the compilation fails complaining about unparseable characteres: "unmappable character for encoding UTF8"

Is there a way to configure character encoding in Jenkins so this doesn't happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved it using encoding="iso-8859-15" in javac and javadoc ant tasks, in order to force the character encoding it should use.